# How to build an android project depending on another project

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk

I try to build an android project depending on OpenCV. But got

```
cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class utils
[javac] location: package org.opencv
[javac]                     Mat imagePointsMat = org.opencv.utils.vector_Point_to_Mat(im
```

it looks like, the 'ant compile' command under my project does not compile the OpenCV project first, but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your library in the CLASSPATH! If you are using Eclipse, go to your Android project, right click on it and choose Java Build Path. In there select Libraries path and add your library (either JAR file, class folder, etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works in Eclipse. But I need to do it with ant in command line.

Comment: And I have executed android update project --path . --target 3 --library=../OpenCV-2.3.1